# query on system.data.sqlite not working

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I have a sqlite database with table called File, that has a column called FilePath, of type Text.

On that table there is an entry whose FilePath has the value `f9a35e24-bce9-46c8-bbc0-02a005455fe3`(the toString of a random GUID).

If I try the following query on SQLiteStudio, it outputs the entry.

```
SELECT FilePath FROM File WHERE FilePath = 'f9a35e24-bce9-46c8-bbc0-02a005455fe3'
```

However, using the code below, that uses the `System.Data.SQLite` external assembly, it never retrieves the entry.

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString);

SQLiteCommand cmd = 
    new SQLiteCommand(@"SELECT FilePath FROM File WHERE FilePath = '@Where';", conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@Where", DbType.String).Value = 
    "f9a35e24-bce9-46c8-bbc0-02a005455fe3";

conn.Open();

SQLiteDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine("yes");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("not");
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need single quote `'` around the `@where` parameter. Your code should be like this:

```
SQLiteCommand cmd = 
new SQLiteCommand(@"SELECT FilePath FROM File WHERE FilePath = @Where", conn);
```